# Super Search - Matching any of keywords with inclusive set to no not working

Tags: solspace, supersearch

We are attempting to use Super Search to show articles which match any any of the keywords in a search field, rather than having to match them all.

Passing the form through to our results page gives a URL as follows:

```
http://mydomain.com/search/search&keywords=duke+laser/
```

Whilst searching for 'duke' on its own returns one result and searching for 'laser' on its own returns a separate result, searching for both, as above, returns no results.

We have tried both 'inclusive_keywords="no"' and 'where="any"'.

Hard coding in 'keywords="duke+laser"' returns no results either, but hard coding in 'keywords="duke|laser"' does work.

EE 2.8.1
SS 2.1.4

Any help would be appreciated!

Mike

Comment: I can reproduce this on my side as well. Asked other staff to try and confirm this. Filed as a bug report for now.

Comment: Are there any core files we can edit to resolve this? Any ideas when the release fixing this will be?